# How to use String.escapeSingleQuote method

Tags: apex

Please let me know. Is below the code in proper way of using String.singleEscapeQuotes. I am using singleEscapeQuotes for security purpose.

Before use:

```
string strValue = '';
strValue =  string.valueof(contactDesc.get('Description'));
if (strValue != null  && strValue.contains('Summary Description')) {
//logic
}

public customWrapper(Id accId){
String auQuery = 'Select Id, Name' + cuFields + ' From Account Where Id =: accId';
accMap = new Map < Id, Account > (getAccData(Database.query((auQuery)));
}
```

After use:

```
string strValue = '';
strValue =  string.valueof(contactDesc.get('Description'));
if (String.escapeSingleQuotes(strValue) != null  && String.escapeSingleQuotes(strValue).contains('Summary Description')) {
//logic
}


public customWrapper(Id accId){
String auQuery = 'Select Id, Name' + cuFields + ' From Account Where Id =: accId';
accMap = new Map < Id, Account > (getAccData(Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(auQuery))));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You need to be concerned about [SOQL injection](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_soql_injection) in dynamically constructed SOQL queries that can include user input. (See the linked Trailhead module for lots of details). The vulnerability is typically in a dynamic `WHERE` clause, which you don't have here; however, at minimum to stop static analyzers from claiming you have an injection vulnerability, what you should be escaping is `cuFields` - the text you dynamically add to your SOQL query.

```
Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(auQuery))
```

This doesn't do anything here because your query doesn't contain any single quotes. If you had a `WHERE` clause that included legitimate single quotes, this would break your query.

```
if (String.escapeSingleQuotes(strValue) != null  && String.escapeSingleQuotes(strValue).contains('Summary Description')) {
```

There is no need to perform quote escaping prior to running string comparisons.